# Figure out why the "System" process on Android is using a lot of CPU

Tags: battery

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 with Android Lollipop.  My phone was feeling sluggish.  Using an app called "OS Monitor", I see that the "System" process (not to be confused with "Android System") is using a lot of CPU time.  The CPU percentage goes as high as 50% on a quad-core processor.

I looked at the Battery screen in settings and it says the "System" process  is using the most of the battery.  How do I figure out what inside "System" is consuming so much CPU time?  What app will reveal what is going on inside?

Rebooting the phone temporarily fixes the problem.

Note: The app or solution has to work on a non-rooted phone.